# Login failed for user 'sa'. WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection

Tags: sql, webmatrix-2

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        if (!WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.Initialized)
        {
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
        }
        WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("Admin", "Admin");
        Roles.CreateRole("Administrator");
        Roles.AddUserToRole("Admin", "Administrator");

    }

}





<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=DEV001;Initial Catalog=SimpleMembership;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=***********" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I couldnt see what is wrong. I can connect to database with SQL management studio or in vs2013 server explorer. I copied connection string from properties in server explorer defaultConnection. But already ı cant login for same password and user when ı run application . I get error

Login failed for user 'sa'.

source error.

```
 if (!WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.Initialized)
    {
        WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("DefaultConnection", "UserProfile", "UserId", "UserName", autoCreateTables: true);
    }
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Could you provide connectionStrings XML element from Web.config for **DefaultConnection**?

Comment: I have added full xml for connection.

Comment: Try to double check password. Put semicolon after password in connection string **Password=***********;"**